# how to open orbeon samples in form builder to edit

Tags: forms, orbeon, xforms

I have installed orbeon under tomcat and I can open Form builder to create new form

1- How can I open one of orbeon samples in Form builder to **edit**

For instance this sample is under "../resources/apps/xforms-wizard-switch" and I can open with a browser to see the form  but I can't open through form builder to edit the form

2-It seems when I create a new form through form builder it is saved through a database 
  How can I force orbeon to save form detail such as view.xhtml and page-flow.xml in
 file system

3- if I can't save a new form through form builder in file system then how can I pass 
   sample data to a form , similar to sample"../resources/apps/xforms-bookcast/sample-data.xml"

Answer (score 0):

1. Those samples were created by hand and not with Form Builder. So you cannot open them with Form Builder. The Form Builder samples which you *can* edit are available at `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/summary`
2. You cannot: the form definitions are always saved to a database. You could do so by hand but we don't recommend it.
3. You can use the form to enter that data, which will be stored in the database. Alternatively, you could write that data directly to the database, or use the [persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api) to do so. But you cannot simply have a file on disk.